# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type CDSessionBean with qualifiers @Default

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

Im new in Java EE 7, and for learning im doing an app that manage a CD database.
My simple app worked until i have insert e EJB module, that represent a java bean singleton, whose work is to populate my database with some record. Let's go to code:
This is my beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="CDArchiveEJBPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
    <class>entities.CD</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
       <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my Session Bean:

```
package ejbs;

import entities.CD;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;


/**
 *
 * @author gfucc
 */

@Stateless
public class CDSessionBean implements CDSessionBeanRemote 
{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CDArchiveEJBPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<CD> findAll() 
    {
        TypedQuery<CD> query = em.createNamedQuery("CD.findAll", CD.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public CD findCDbyID(CD cd, Object id) 
    {
        return em.find(CD.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void createCD(CD cd) 
    {
        em.persist(cd);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCD(CD cd) 
    {
        em.remove(cd);
    }

    @Override
    public CD update(CD cd) 
    {
        return em.merge(cd);
    }



}
```

With these elements my project work! (I think is not necessary to post my entity class).

Now, after that i inserted a database populator as a singleton java bean (my exercise request them). This is the code of my database populator:

```
package ejbs;

import entities.CD;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;


/**
 *
 * @author gfucc
 */
@Singleton
@Startup
public class DatabasePopulator 
{
    @Inject
    private CDSessionBean cdEJB;

    @PostConstruct
    private void populateDB()
    {
        cdEJB.createCD(new CD("DefaultCD1", "DefaultAuthor", 1));
        cdEJB.createCD(new CD("DefaultCD2", "DefaultAuthor2", 2));
    }
}
```

It's very simple to understand...but my project with this java bean doesn't work! The problem is an unsatisfied dependencies injection... I searched for some solution, and i've tried some of them. I tried to use the remote interface at injection point, but doesn't work. I tried to change bean-discovery-mode = "annotated" to "all" and still not working. I tried to use qualifier(@Default and custom qualifier on CDSessionBean)... but doesn't work again. Maybe CDI is not enabled?? If yes how can i enabled it?
Thanks a lot :D

Edit:
This is the code of my DatabasePopulator that use interface at injection point:

```
package ejbs;

import entities.CD;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.inject.Inject;

/**
 *
 * @author gfucc
 */
@Stateless
@Singleton
public class DatabasePopulator {

    @Inject
    private CDSessionBeanRemote cdEJB;

    @PostConstruct
    private void populateDB()
    {
        cdEJB.createCD(new CD("DefaultCD1", "DefaultAuthor", 1));
        cdEJB.createCD(new CD("DefaultCD2", "DefaultAuthor2", 2));
    }
}
```

This is the full stacktrace if i use remote interface at injection point:

> Informazioni:   visiting unvisited references Informazioni:   visiting
>   unvisited references Grave:   The annotation symbol defined in
>   super-class is not compatible with Session ejb DatabasePopulator. 
>   symbol: TYPE location: class ejbs.DatabasePopulator
>
> Grave:   Annotations processing failed for
>   file:/C:/Users/gfucc/workspaceNetbeans/CDArchiveEJB/build/classes/
>   Informazioni:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258 Informazioni:   /file:/C:/Users/gfucc/workspaceNetbeans/CDArchiveEJB/build/classes/_CDArchiveEJBPU
>   login successful Informazioni:   Portable JNDI names for EJB
>   CDSessionBean:
>   [java:global/CDArchiveEJB/CDSessionBean!ejbs.CDSessionBeanRemote,
>   java:global/CDArchiveEJB/CDSessionBean] Informazioni:
>   Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB CDSessionBean:
>   [ejbs.CDSessionBeanRemote#ejbs.CDSessionBeanRemote,
>   ejbs.CDSessionBeanRemote] Informazioni:   Portable JNDI names for EJB
>   DatabasePopulator:
>   [java:global/CDArchiveEJB/DatabasePopulator!ejbs.DatabasePopulator,
>   java:global/CDArchiveEJB/DatabasePopulator] WARN:   WELD-000411:
>   Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public
>   org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types.
>   Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type
>   with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
>   [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private
>   org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types.
>   Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type
>   with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
>   [BackedAnnotatedMethod]
>   org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType, BeanManager) receives events for all
>   annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or
>   a generic type with bounds. Grave:   Exception during lifecycle
>   processing org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI
>   deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type
>   CDSessionBeanRemote with qualifiers @Default   at injection point
>   [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ejbs.DatabasePopulator.cdEJB
>   at ejbs.DatabasePopulator.cdEJB(DatabasePopulator.java:0)     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:234)  at
>   org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)   at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408:
>   Unsatisfied dependencies for type CDSessionBeanRemote with qualifiers
>   @Default   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private
>   ejbs.DatabasePopulator.cdEJB   at
>   ejbs.DatabasePopulator.cdEJB(DatabasePopulator.java:0)    at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:504)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:479)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:443)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)     ...
>   41 more
>
> Grave:   Exception while loading the app Informazioni:
>   /file:/C:/Users/gfucc/workspaceNetbeans/CDArchiveEJB/build/classes/_CDArchiveEJBPU
>   logout successful Grave:   Exception while loading the app : CDI
>   deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type
>   CDSessionBeanRemote with qualifiers @Default   at injection point
>   [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ejbs.DatabasePopulator.cdEJB
>   at ejbs.DatabasePopulator.cdEJB(DatabasePopulator.java:0)
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408:
>   Unsatisfied dependencies for type CDSessionBeanRemote with qualifiers
>   @Default   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private
>   ejbs.DatabasePopulator.cdEJB   at
>   ejbs.DatabasePopulator.cdEJB(DatabasePopulator.java:0)    at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:504)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:479)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:443)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)     at
>   org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)   at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Inject EJB by interface and post full stacktrace.

Comment: @Geinmachi I ve edited my question, and i posted the full stacktrace of my error if i use the remote interface at the injection point. Thanks for attention

Comment: Do you have the same error if you inject EJB by `@EJB` instead of `@Inject`?

Comment: Ok, my ejbs are deployed... but my DatabasePopulator still doesn't work... The error is this:
[full stacktrace](http://www.mediafire.com/download/gsg753opjhml6av/stackTrace.txt)
I ve a NullPointerExeception but i don't know where!

Comment: Sorry but not going to click on a mediafire link.  Please post to pastebin or something like that, or inline the stacktrace here.  One issue I do see is that you have both `@Stateless` and `@Singleton`, its one or the other.

Comment: @JohnAment I removed '@Stateless' but i ve the same error. Here the full stacktrace: [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/b3zkaP73)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i resolved removing '@Stateless' and annoting with '@Startup'. My distraction, i removed it during correction, in fact if can you see in my first DatabasePopulator code there was Startup annotation and in the second no! Sorry :D But the error were to use Injection and Stateless... so thanks!